# 403 Forbidden error for Gremlin to AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

I'm trying to setup my AWS Neptune environment by following the instruction at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started.html . The setup seems to be fine, and I could check the status by using the Neptune Notebook install. The status message as:

```
{
  "status": "healthy",
  "startTime": "Tue May 12 04:24:52 UTC 2020",
  "dbEngineVersion": "1.0.2.2.R2",
  "role": "writer",
  "gremlin": {
    "version": "tinkerpop-3.4.3"
  },
  "sparql": {
    "version": "sparql-1.1"
  },
  "labMode": {
    "ObjectIndex": "disabled",
    "ReadWriteConflictDetection": "enabled"
  }
}
```

However I can't connect to it via my Gremlin console in EC2 client instance, I'm getting the 403 forbidden error as below:

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/neptune-remote.yaml
WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster  - Using deprecated SSL trustCertChainFile support
ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler  - Could not process the response
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 403 Forbidden
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:226)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker.finishHandshake(WebSocketClientHandshaker.java:276)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketClientHandler.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
```

The IAM role that I assigned to the EC2 instance has the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "neptune-db:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:neptune-db:ap-southeast-2:<my aws account number>:*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My neptune-remote.yaml file as below:

```
hosts: [<my neptune cluster name>.cluster-<cluster id>.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com]
port: 8182
connectionPool: { enableSsl: true, trustCertChainFile: "SFSRootCAG2.pem"}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

In order to debug this issue, I have tried to use apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console version 3.4.1, 3.4.3 & 3.4.6. All have same error response

I have also tried to successfully telnet to above host port as below, so it wasn't a SG or connection issue:

```
$ telnet <my neptune cluster name>.cluster-<cluster id>.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com 8182
Trying 172.30.1.200...
Connected to xxxxx-xxxxxxxx.cluster-xxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I have struggle on this for a while, any help/hint will be much appreciated

thanks!

Comment: Happy to try and help. A few questions that should help narrow down the issue...Do you have IAM Authentication enabled on your cluster? From the EC2 instance are you able to do: curl <cluster>:8182/status ? Is the EC2 instance in the same VPC as Neptune?

Comment: Hi Kelvin,  many thanks for your help. i have just tried to do curl <cluster>:8182/status, and getting the following result: curl: (52) Empty reply from server. The ec2 instance is in the same VPC as Neptune, but it's sitting on the public subnet as the AWS instruction.

Comment: Does your Neptune cluster have IAM security enabled? If it does you have to sign requests using SIG V4. Can you curl the /status API of the cluster?

Comment: You should use HTTPS in your curl command. `curl https://<cluster-endpoint>:8182/status`. Check if this works or not. I'm fairly sure it should give you a 403 as well, if IAM Auth is indeed enabled in your cluster. To check that, use the Neptune Console or CLI to describe the details of the cluster.

Comment: The IAM db Auth is enable for Neptune cluster. when I tried to curl https://<cluster-endpoint>:8182/status, I'm getting {"requestId":"....","code":"AccessDeniedException","detailedMessage":"Missing Authentication Token"} error.

Comment: thanks for your hint of using SIG V4, I have tried to follow the steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-console.html. Including update the neptune-remote.yaml file to new channelizer. The 403 forbidden issue has gone. But i'm going the following error: 
WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Host  - Marking Host{address=<host name>.cluster-<cluster id>.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com/<ip>:8182, hostUri=ws://<cluster endpoint>:8182/gremlin} as unavailable. Trying to reconnect.
==>Configured <cluster endpoint>/<private ip>:8182

Comment: oh! thanks all for your help. Finally I'm able to connected to the Neptune DB cluster with apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console version 3.3 with SIG V4.

Comment: I got stuck at next step after the connection, as I keep getting NoSuchMethodError for org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.RequestOptions$Builder.userAgent. I have post a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810488/tinkerpop-gremlin-console-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-tinkerpop-gre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an answer based on the comments in case others find this also.

If IAM authentication is enabled for the Amazon Neptune cluster all query requests must be signed using SIG V4. See [1] for more information.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-console.html