# Tinkerpop Gremlin Console: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.RequestOptions$Builder.userAgent

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

As my last post at [403 Forbidden error for Gremlin to AWS Neptune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61768272/403-forbidden-error-for-gremlin-to-aws-neptune), I could successfully connect to my Neptune Cluster DB via my Tinkerpop Gremlin console v 3.4.3 that installed at my EC2 instance as v 3.4.1 suggested at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-console.html didn't work for me.

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/neptune-remote.yaml
==>Configured <my neptune>.cluster-cm<cluster id>.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com/<private ip>:8182
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [<my neptune>.cluster-cm<cluster id>.ap-southeast-2.neptune.amazonaws.com/<private ip>:8182] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
```

However, I'm getting NoSuchMethodError error for all Gremlin commands (g.) that I used on the console.

e.g: 
g.V()

```
gremlin> g.V()
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.RequestOptions$Builder.userAgent(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/RequestOptions$Builder;
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]Y
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.RequestOptions$Builder.userAgent(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/RequestOptions$Builder;
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.send(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:214)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:110)
...
```

g.addV('person').property('name', 'justin')

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name', 'justin')
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.RequestOptions$Builder.userAgent(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/RequestOptions$Builder;
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]Y
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.RequestOptions$Builder.userAgent(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/RequestOptions$Builder;
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.send(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:214)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:110)
....
```

I have also tried the latest Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin Console 3.4.6, same error I had...

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the SigV4WebSocketChannelizer to your YAML file?

Answer (score 2):

I think the step you're missing is taking the temporary credentials provided by your EC2 instance's assigned IAM role and pushing those into the Default Credential Provider chain in order for them to be seen by the SigV4Channelizer used by the Gremlin Console.  A high level overview of that process can be seen here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

A more prescriptive way of handling this for Neptune can be found here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-temporary-credentials.html  See the section titled, "Setting Up Amazon EC2 for Neptune IAM Authentication".

Comment: Hi Taylor, I have tried to use "aws configure" to set the default ec2 credentials, and also tried to export the "AWS_xxx" environment variables. I have even tried to use two type of connections. 1) to Neptune cluster with IAM DB enable.. (with SigV4WebSocketChannelizer in YAML file). 2) to Neptune cluster with NO IAM DB enable (with trustCertChainFile: SFSRootCAG2.pem in YAML file)..  Unfortunately same error for both ways of connections

Comment: I'm using Neptune 1.0.2.2.R2 Engine and Gremlin console 3.4.6

Comment: Very odd.  What version of Java are you using?  Make sure you're using Java 8.  Also note that the trustCertChainFile would be needed in either case (whether IAM is enabled or not).  The pem file is used for SSL cert validation.  The SigV4WebSocketChannelizer would only be needed if IAM is enabled.

Comment: I've been unable to recreate this issue. Along with the version of Java you're using, can you also supply the OS version you're using on your EC2 instance?  I'm using Amazon Linux 2 (latest build) with Java 8 and the following yaml file:  

hosts: [cluster.cluster-xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com]
port: 8182
connectionPool: { enableSsl: true, trustCertChainFile: "SFSRootCAG2.pem" }
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 }

I removed the: config: { serializeResultToString: true } to test and it works both ways.

Comment: I have similar yaml file setting as yours, and I'm using openjdk version "1.8.0_252" and latest Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0970010f37c4f9c8d (64-bit x86) on my ec2 instance.

Comment: Oh! I just tried to use Gremlin console 3.4.1 and it's working as expected... I think it's due to Incompatible Version issue. I was using Gremlin console 3.4.6

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to use Gremlin console 3.4.1 and it's working as expected... I think it's due to Incompatible Version issue. I was using Gremlin console 3.4.6

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Very odd though, as we've tested 3.4.6 and it works fine.  So I'm wondering if there were some other configuration options in your 3.4.6 installation that may have been causing some issues.  But yeah, presently Neptune supports up to 3.4.3, but we haven't seen any issues with the 3.4.6 console up until now.